# Package 'AndroidTools_Xamarin,version=25.2.5.1' failed to install

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Trying to install VS 2017 community edition but installation finishes with warning. Below are the details from my log file.

Also when I create a new project using crossplatform Xamarin, the VS is showing following error.

[image]
Please advise.

===============================================

Something went wrong with the install.

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

```
1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again
```

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

```
Package 'AndroidTools_Xamarin,version=25.2.5.1' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidTools_Xamarin;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command "& """C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\AndroidTools_Xamarin,version=25.2.5.1\AndroidSDKPrivateInstall.ps1""" -Package tools -FileName tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip -Version 25.2.5 -AndroidHome """C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk""" -RequestedAVDs """""" -Operation Install; exit $LastExitCode"
        Return code: 1
        Return code details: Incorrect function.
    Log
        C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20171011180546_366_AndroidTools_Xamarin.log
    Impacted workloads
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26929.2)
    Impacted components
        Android SDK setup (API level 25) (Component.Android.SDK25,version=15.0.26919.1)
        Google Android Emulator (API Level 25) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API25,version=15.0.26929.2)
```

Comment: would be grateful if any moderator can format the question? I tried but its not showing properly, Thanks

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the Android SDK for 7.0+ installed, this is done via the Android SDK Manager. Once you verify that is installed, change your `Xamarin.Android` application project to target at least the Android 7.0 Framework, not the 6.0 that your project is currently set to as the `Xamarin.Android` Support libraries version 25.2.5.1 require 7.0+. FYI: This requirement is in the error message but only included in your screenshot, that is one reason you should not use images to post error text as it is not searchable and indexable by Stackoverflow.

Comment: So, should we not select the Android related components while installation VS2017, and install the required libraries separately using Android SDK Manager? And then point our Android project to manually installed SDK? Correct?

Comment: You do not have to "re-install" anything, but use the Android SDK Manager (either Google's or the built-in one in Visual Studio and install 7.0+ SDKs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the version of Xamarine and it worked. So looks like the pervious installation was not correct.